# Table imported from excel not reflecting in DB despite success message of import

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Figure 1: (No DB option to select the DB or create a DB)

[image]

I am trying to import an excel into my DB . DB Name is Tableau Sales analytics. When I select destination as SQL Native client and authenticate using windows authentication, I am not getting any option to select DB in this screen as shown in figure 1.

Figure 2: Selected the DB where I want excel Customers to be copied:

[image]

I select the db and corresponding table (highlighted in yellow) in *Select Source Tables and Views*

Figure 3: I get success message that excel has been copied in db 'Tableau Sales analytics'

[image]

But when I check for the table in my DB, I get no table at all

Figure 4: Not able to find the excel as table in my db

[image]

Comment: `Customers` <> `Customers$`. Your import also specifies a schema and you don't in the latter image. Voting to close as typographical.

Comment: Right click database on the left side, click refresh

Comment: Does your database really have a schema with the name as the database too? That must be really confusing to work with.

Comment: Final note, the SQL Native Client has been deprecated for years, why are using that and not MSSQLOLEDB?